# Eliminating a white spaces from a string except for end of the string

Tags: python, regex

I want to eliminate white spaces in a string except for end of the string

code:

```
sentence = ['He must be having a great time/n                           ', 'It is fun to play chess      ', 'Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ']
pattern = "\s+^[\s+$]"
res = [re.sub(pattern,', ', line) for line in sentence]

print(res)
```

But...

output is same input list.

```
['He must be having a great time/n                           ', 'It is fun to play chess      ', 'Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ']
```

Can anyone suggest the right solution.

code:

```
sentence = ['He must be having a great time                           ', 'It is fun to play chess      ', 'Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ']
pattern = "\s+^[\s+$]"
res = [re.sub(pattern,', ', line) for line in sentence]

print(res)
```

But...

output is same input list.

```
['He must be having a great time/n                           ', 'It is fun to play chess      ', 'Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ']
```

expected output:

```
['He,must,be,having,a,great,time', 'It,is,fun,to,play,chess', 'Sometimes,TT,is,better,than,Badminton ']
```

Comment: `[','.join(i.split()) for i in sentence]`

Comment: OP, you also seem to have a wrong newline escape in `He must be having a great time/n`, it's not `/n` but `\n`.

Comment: Your stated requirement doesn't match your output example. You say "...eliminate white spaces in a string except for end of the string" yet your output shows trailing whitespace as having been removed

Answer (score 0):

We can first strip off leading/trailing whitespace, then do a basic replacement of space to comma:

```py
import re

sentence = ['He must be having a great time\n                           ', 'It is fun to play chess      ', 'Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ']
output = [re.sub(r'\s+', ',', x.strip()) for x in sentence]
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
['He,must,be,having,a,great,time',
 'It,is,fun,to,play,chess',
 'Sometimes,TT,is,better,than,Badminton']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simpler `split/join` method (timeit: 1.48 µs ± 74 ns).

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will split on groups of whitespace characters (space or newline for instance).

[`str.join(iter)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will join the elements of iter with the str it is used on.

Demo:

```py
sentence = [
    "He must be having a great time\n                           ",
    "It is fun to play chess      ",
    "Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ",
]
[",".join(s.split()) for s in sentence]
```

gives

```py
['He,must,be,having,a,great,time',
 'It,is,fun,to,play,chess',
 'Sometimes,TT,is,better,than,Badminton']
```

---

Second method, `strip/replace` (timeit: 1.56 µs ± 107 ns).

[`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes all whitespace characters at the beginning and then end of str.

[`str.replace(old, new)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replaces all occurences of `old` in str with `new` (works because you have single spaces between words in your strings).

Demo:

```py
sentence = [
    "He must be having a great time\n                           ",
    "It is fun to play chess      ",
    "Sometimes TT is better than Badminton             ",
]

[s.strip().replace(" ", ",") for s in sentence]
```

gives

```py
['He,must,be,having,a,great,time',
 'It,is,fun,to,play,chess',
 'Sometimes,TT,is,better,than,Badminton']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def eliminating_white_spaces(list):
for string in range(0,len(list)):
    if ' ' in list[string] and string+1==len(list):
        pass
    else:  
        list[string]=str(list[string]).replace(' ',',')
return list
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.

Comment: You have shadowed *list* which is rarely a good idea. Your indentation is wrong. This does not eliminate whitespace. There are several characters that are considered to be whitespace - not just ' '. The first parameter to range defaults to zero so no need to be explicit

Comment: I am sorry I will try to improve